# Counting the Maximum Values Occur in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Following are two related tables

```
CREATE TABLE SCHOOL
(School_ID char(3), School_Name char(15), School_Address char(15), School_City char(15), School_State char(2), School_Zip char(5), School_Type char(15));
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(School_ID char(3), St_LastName char(15), St_FirstName char(15), St_DOB char(15), St_SS# char(15), St_Address char(15),St_City char(15), St_State char(2),st_Zip char(5), st_phone char(15));
```

I tried to write query in access :**Display school id with the most students**
But my query shows student name with maximum School_ID instead of occurunces.Please Help me

Query is as followed:

```
SELECT STUDENT.School_ID, SCHOOL.School_Name, STUDENT.St_LastName, STUDENT.St_FirstName
FROM (SELECT MAX(STUDENT.School_ID) as max
FROM SCHOOL INNER JOIN STUDENT ON (SCHOOL.School_ID = STUDENT.School_ID) AND (SCHOOL.School_ID = STUDENT.School_ID)
)  AS Overallcount, SCHOOL INNER JOIN STUDENT ON (SCHOOL.School_ID = STUDENT.School_ID) AND (SCHOOL.School_ID = STUDENT.School_ID)
WHERE (((STUDENT.School_ID)=([Overallcount].[max])));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do an aggregation and use `top` and `order by`:

```
select top   1    school_id
from student
group by school_id
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

Comment: Nice. Note that MS Access will return matches for the Top records, that is, more that one record if two records have the same count.

Comment: This answer return only 1 value. WHATIF,If 2 students add records corresponding to  STUDENT.school_id 1.It should return 2 times school_id(means it should show 1 two times)

Comment: @UsmanShafiArain . . . Your question says that you want to return the school id with the most students, which is what this answer does.  If you want to return all the students in the school, you should probably ask another question, provide sample data, and the results that you want.